# Problems Linking Up a Switch in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am having trouble linking up a switch. I understand how to connect the switch as an outlet and have it have actions change the boolean state of a value, but I need the switch to perform an action in a different view controller.

Here's the situation: I have a main table view controller, called View Controller A. I have a second view controller, lets call it view controller B, that controls a menu sidebar (on a regular view controller, not a table view) triggered by a bar item. I want to be able to open up the menu, hit a switch in the sidebar, and have something change in the main table view that is controlled by view controller A.

Is there any way that I can accomplish this? I seem to have no way of accessing or changing the IBOutlets in View Controller A from B. Is there a way that I can have the action in B linked with the switch change the boolean state of a value, and have an action waiting in controller A that will respond to a change in boolean? I am not sure how to solve this problem. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [delegation pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm). You'll have an action waiting in controller A, but instead of responding to value changed in B the action will be triggered by B when appropriate

ViewControllerB.h

```
// Create delegate protocol and property
@protocol ViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)switchPressed:(BOOL)switchStatus;
@end

@interface ViewControllerB : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic,weak) id<ViewControllerBDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

ViewControllerB.m

```
// When switch is tapped, call delegate method if it is implemented by delegate object
- (IBAction)flip: (id) sender {
    UISwitch *onoff = (UISwitch *) sender;
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(switchPressed:)]) {
        [self.delegate switchPressed:onoff.on];
    }
}
```

ViewControllerA.h

```
// Conform to ViewControllerB protocol
#import ViewControllerB.h

@interface ViewControllerA : NSObject,ViewControllerBDelegate
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
// Set self (VC A) as VC B's delegate
- (void)ViewDidLoadOrSomeOtherFunction {    
    ViewControllerB *vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
    vcB setDelegate = self;
}

// Implement delegate method
- (void)switchPressed:(BOOL)switchStatus {
    if (switchStatus) {
        // Make changes on VC A
    }
}
```